# Partitions become free space after every reboot

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I just bought a brand new laptop computer. Unfortunately it had problem and the support service had to give it a new HDD.

After successfully reinstalled Windows, I noticed a strange thing that all of my partitions, other than the Windows partition, become a whole big free space after every reboot!

Here are all the steps that I did in attempt to install Windows:

- Used *Partition Wizard* in a rescue CD to create the partitions but all as **Logical** without a **Primary** one.
- Started Windows installation, tried to delete then re-create the **Primary** partition but not successful, so I went back to *Partition Wizard* to change the first partition to **Primary**, leaving other partitions as it.
- Installed Windows, partitions kept disappearing. I re-created them using *Disk Management* and did a full format for all of them but nothing changes. *DriveXML* shows an error message of missing signature in partition table.

Can anyone please tell me if there is anything wrong in my process above? What should I do with my computer now?

Comment: Try checking the S.M.A.R.T. reading of your hard drive. It is possible you have a defective disk.

Comment: Are you saying that you could not achieve [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers_new_1/windows-7-install-size.jpg) when re-installing windows? Then, without creating a new partition, just click the next button?

Comment: The terms "primary" and "logical" are meaningful for partitions only on MBR disks, which implies a BIOS-mode Windows install. (OTOH, if these are logical *volumes*, then that's another kettle of fish.) Most new installs are in EFI mode, and Windows' handling of logical partitions has been going down hill for years, so if you've really got a BIOS/MBR install, I recommend you re-do it in EFI mode to avoid logical partitions.